# uninitialized constant Die (NameError)

Tags: ruby, nameerror, uninitialized-constant

I'm receiving an Uninitialized constant error from my code. I have searched around with no luck. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
Class Die

    def initialize 

        roll
    end

    def roll

        @num_showing = 1 + rand(6)
    end

    def showing

        @num_showing
    end

    def cheat
        puts "Enter the die # (1-6)"
        @num_showing = gets.chomp
        while @numshowing > 6 and @numshowing < 0

            puts "Enter the die # (1-6)"
            @num_showing = gets.chomp

        end
    end

puts Die.new.cheat
```

Comment: It's class, not Class (note the capital letter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change `Class` to `class`
2. Add an extra `end` at the end of the class definition. Looks like you're not closing the `while` loop.

Comment: 3. Better indentation :P

Comment: I don't think he's missing an end. Edit: Never mind.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm new to programming any tips on indentation?

Comment: @LaurentL Piccolo's indentation of your code is fairly standard. Some might indent only 2 spaces instead of 4.

Comment: @LaurentL I generally indent my code with 2 spaces, but on Stack Overflow, I have a habit of using 4 spaces because that's how you start a code block.